# Restrict page access to colorbox

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, colorbox

I have a form built on a standalone PHP page, but I've only want that page to be access when it's being requested via jQuery Colorbox.

You can see the website in question here: http://tinyurl.com/96uhuer

When the user clicks on one of the 'Email Us Now' buttons the form pops up in Colorbox. However, as an example, the user could right click on the button and choose to 'Open in a new tab', which would open the form's standalone page.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also user could click center mouse button and etc. The simplest solution is remove link, then you can opel dialog like this:

```
$.colorbox({href:'http://www.formurl.com/form.php'})
```

this solution show's hard coded link, but you can create css `class` and `data-attribute` and then read it on `click` event.

Comment: Thanks Webdeveloper. This is essentially what I was looking for. However I think in the end I'll go with @Jeremy's suggestion and call the form as inline content instead.

Comment: @norsewulf it's your choice, but his solution does not solve your problem, right click will open same page with selector.

Comment: I'm aware of that... That's why I'll probably just place the form inside the footer and open it as an iframe.

I tried to do it this way, but since it's on an <a> tag an href attribute should be defined, and I don't want to give it a hash tag. Unless you know of a better practice.

Comment: Thanks again for answering the question. Once I got the issue of my href solved I have stuck with this solution. I just had to place `javascript:void(0)` in the href in order for the call to work on my <a> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in a situation like that, if you don't intend to use it in any way as a standalone page, then don't make it a separate page.  Take a look at the [ColorBox demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/) , particularly the *Inline HTML* sample.

You'll notice that the link doesn't contain a link to a separate page, but rather it includes a link to an element on the same page (inline).  This is what you should be after.

If you use the inline method, if user decides to open the link on a new tab, it will show the same page they are on and not your email form.

Comment: Thanks I've done it this way before. I figured this might be the best solution. Just wondered if there was a way to do it this way that was still 'correct'.